# Getting count of intersect in Arcade attribute rule in enterprise geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, arcade, attribute-rules, error-002717

Having  two feature classes in an enterprise geodatabase like

```
-  EGDB.North.Parcels
-  EGDB.North.ProjectsInvest
```

I am trying to get the total count of Intersection between  `EGDB.North.Projects` in `EGDB.North.ProjectsInvest` using attribute rules like this

```
var intersects = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($datastore, "EGDB.North.Parcels"), Geometry($feature)); 
return Count(intersects) ;
```

but I am getting this error

> 002717: Invalid Arcade expression

```
var intersects = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($datastore, "EGDB.North.Parcels"), Geometry($feature));
if(Count(intersects)>0){
  return Count(intersects);
}
else{
  return 0;
}
```

Everything is fine when data loaded in FGDB! but in the database it is not working.

Comment: Does it work without the database name qualifier? North.Parcels instead of EGDB.North.Parcels

Comment: Thanks for reply Dowlers, I actually tried both `"EGDB.North.Parcels"` and `"Parcels"` already and same thing was happening

Comment: what about just "North.Parcels"? Also does it make a difference when you enable "exclude From application evaluation" ?